# What does the lucky foot do?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

The wiki states that the lucky foot raises luck. Unfortunately, it fails to state just what that means. So, what does raising my luck do?

Comment: It makes you win.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to the other answer, I have experimentally found that the lucky foot increases the chances of winning at the shell game in the arcade. [The wiki](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Rooms) says that the probability of winning on any single run is 33%, but when playing as Cain I have recorded a greater than 50% win rate (so far it seems to be 66%).

**Edit:** according to discussion on the [item page](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Items) on the wiki, the foot also makes you only get good pills. The comment said that collecting it turned a bad pill into a good pill like the PhD item.

**Edit 2:** it appears that the Womb levels decrease or nullify the effect of the Lucky Foot. I went to an arcade on The Womb 2 and found that my win rate was below 50%.

I tested with 140 consecutive runs of the shell game in The Womb 2 and I won 77 times, so it looks like the win chance is a bit over 50%, but definitely not 66%.

In addition, the lucky foot increases the chance of getting an item from the beggar. Without the lucky foot, it often takes 4 or 5 coins before the beggar will drop a single item. With the lucky foot, however, I have never seen it take more than 3 coins for him to drop something.

Comment: Can any information about the slot machine be added?  Does the Lucky Foot increase your chance to win at them?

Comment: I don't have that information right now, but if I get a chance I'll test it. And if someone else tests it, I'll put it in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look at the [items page](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Items) on the wiki, there are a couple of people there who state the foot does several thing:

- Slot machine winnings
- Improved pill effects
- Easier rooms
- Better items found

While as a programmer it makes sense to me that all the above are based on some global "luck" factor, which the lucky foot improves, I can't say I have actually noticed any of the above in one of my playthroughs (that doesn't mean that the effects aren't too subtle to easily notice).

What I did notice, personally, is that when I play as Cain, who starts with the lucky foot, I tend to get more pick-up drops once I clear a room of baddies.

Comment: So far the only effect I'm reasonably certain of is a higher coin and heart drop rate, but that's based on one playthrough with Cain. I'm hoping there's a more definitive answer than the comments section of the wiki.

Comment: @Fambida: Then your experience is similar to mine. I doubt you can get a "definitive" answer for this, unless someone actually takes the time to sit down and perform some statistics. Even then, there is no telling how many factors effect the things I listed above, so I'm not sure anything short of disassembling the game can give the correct answer.