# Does the Lucky Foot affect the Slot machine or not?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

So yeah the wiki says that it does increase the chances of winning at the Slot Machine but it also says that it doesn't. I would like a definitive answer to if the Lucky Foot does or does not affect the Slot Machine.

I know it affects the Fortune Telling Machine and Shell game.

Wiki: http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Lucky_Foot

Comment: No it's not a duplicate question, if you look you'll see they don't really get into the Slot machine, they say it affects the winning stating the wiki as the source. But the wiki is conflicting as I stated in the question.

Comment: The question has already been asked, however.  I'll request a clarification of the answers to include information about the slot machine, but this question is still asking about a subset of information of the original.

Comment: Alright fair enough i don't really know how you are organized on this site, should i post my question as a comment on that question or will you handle it?

Comment: Unfortunately, you need at least 50 rep to leave comments.  I've [requested an update, specifically for the Slot Machine](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32110/what-does-the-lucky-foot-do#comment143153_32541), and if there's no action within a couple days, I'll bounty it in the hopes that will help.

Comment: @fbueckert You shouldn't have said that. Now I have an incentive to not figure it out until you bounty the question.

Comment: I'll gladly help you test it if you want, can't comment on the other question.